# Better Heatmap Visualization in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I would like to have more shades to be present on my heatmap. Can anyone help me in  it? I also added the summary of my matrix dataset.

[image]

The heatmap code that I used are as follows:

```
heatmap.2(matrix,
          Rowv = NA,
          main = "Cost Rankings Per DRG Definiion (Darker Shade = More Expensive) ", 
          xlab = "DRG Definition ID",
          ylab = "States", 
          Colv = NA, 
          scale = "column", 
          col = coul, 
          key = FALSE,
          margins = c(5,5), 
          cexRow = 0.9, 
          cexCol = 0.9,
          trace = "none")
```

The summary of the matrix dataset is as follows:

```
     > dput(head(matrix,4))
 matrix <- structure(c(156023.01, 934292.2, 565543.16, 859246.77, NA, 647281.97, 
 243467.03, 222016.05, 279984.88, 1785117.72, 1210217.08, 1738388.11, 
 277346.4, 3231424.9, 1784411.7, 2539940.3, 39613, 1146810.7, 
 529727.86, 986997.67, 29115.06, 1411979.35, 664273.27, 668479.85, 
 16767.96, 252979.91, 129183.95, 194504.99, 12812.02, 341007.53, 
 217723.31, 332953.97, 97131.88, 1128489.3, 282132.58, 668881.61, 
 20812.06, 429211.14, 256513.98, 811319.88, 17672.06, 778513.41, 
 376581.5, 883744.04, 66327.99, 1895388.92, 1139218.24, 1770164.66, 
 NA, 693016.78, 552007.41, 483426.1, NA, 307001.14, 219478.09, 
 235900.24, 420942.2, 3237765.7, 2324077.5, 3454459.9, 170549.8, 
 4283642.2, 1847497.8, 2111693.5, 80660.06, 2899429.18, 1182813.4, 
 868823.54, 21812, 1623755.28, 750785.96, 255470.21, 176095.6, 
 3042375.8, 2571992.4, 3845886.7, 212915.5, 4328484.6, 2354857.9, 
 2539054.7, 12795.97, 1428190.5, 845619.16, 739186.61, NA, 1088842.33, 
 276199.76, 354687.38, 14492.04, 1030805.76, 662401.33, 201840.91, 
 150853.3, 1650354.2, 1062210.5, 1191047.2, 93799.96, 1971933.46, 
 1004648.69, 942096.11, 53320.05, 607153.18, 536816.15, 675263.5, 
 449583.08, 1566839.43, 1216058.46, 1328317.78, 480714.9, 4432956, 
 2923127.9, 3734036.4, 30351.03, 1845418.4, 490566.1, 887689.86, 
 16899.87, 1417434.85, 537916.35, 957364.87, 119628.09, 554514.83, 
 503740.9, 735597.21, 60498.78, 1570577.33, 831183.79, 1284620.01, 
 69819, 1056405.42, 527309.68, 834961.1, 21140.01, 305148.39, 
 242055.17, 344205.12, 17556.07, 1373699.99, 575169.49, 946223.42, 
 120249.7, 3356762.9, 1830277.9, 1718258.6, 173518.6, 5074740.2, 
 2559276.8, 3491265, 243682.9, 4208010.3, 2177208.7, 2206312.8, 
 NA, 1164790.25, 734920.03, 385705.88, NA, 621862.56, 224061.47, 
 522187.25, NA, 420800.25, 142957.08, 89689.84, 68628, 1598802.4, 
 1007628.56, 1392052.55, 79459.91, 2167594.41, 1331532.99, 1787127.24, 
 80123.96, 1938321.88, 1367553.22, 1591825.51, 45644.95, 1846231.61, 
 845857.62, 799940.15, NA, 1743574.39, 483080.63, 488160.78, 22002.93, 
 1176770.78, 615141.82, 822419.76, 142209.15, 1812647.04, 786067.87, 
 1386309.67, 157990.4, 2685450.6, 1340283, 2853758.4, 97889.07, 
 1061083.38, 472556.81, 854388.81, 8565, 265924.46, 181199.06, 
 385888.2, NA, 567851.31, 392844.96, 565664.86, 203578.2, 1348414.4, 
 689989.1, 744118.2, 223589.1, 2988292, 1905895.2, 2254702.6, 
 NA, 460544.17, 140055.94, 184764.15, 44512, 958991.29, 734571.16, 
 1304339.5, 102656.06, 532474.07, 490331.13, 631933.61, 23193.11, 
 1322236.32, 415219.48, 577760.96, 289623.7, 6196698.2, 2691164.3, 
 3177288.4, 14978.88, 416428.11, 237793.89, 490808.12, 12587.9, 
 1015188.63, 427300.91, 718612.47, 27119.99, 794509.58, 313906.99, 
 629300.12, NA, 586226.22, 313110.32, 368281.97, 324313, 5000112.2, 
 2627556.1, 6328867.9, 101877.93, 1309521.19, 336968.01, 756488.94, 
 3443081, NA, NA, 26893877, 279713.2, 2260306.77, 715682.74, 1102111.17, 
 130221.96, 511929.23, 459850.58, 700773.81, 125233.9, 2377996.8, 
 1422292.5, 2330577.8, 12795.97, 518757.02, 515278.91, 618813.29, 
 163937.1, 1974857.3, 1676696.6, 3153277.4, NA, 405244.61, 238980.44, 
 278851, 135444.01, 981475.9, 526980.36, 764349.78, NA, 323890.23, 
 115054.89, 196663.15, NA, 444982.29, 335713.04, 313231.83, 235511.7, 
 3305858.6, 1296704.2, 2488698.1, NA, 580699.06, 449820.87, 410445.08, 
 34358.09, 1280896.67, 622115.43, 668290.15, 42067.62, 1362265.93, 
 748922.71, 1056568.71, 97188.08, 2612222.56, 1242745.79, 1366078.34, 
 117417.9, 2473766.6, 2048573.4, 1876080.3, 102559.6, 3149369, 
 2145636.7, 2414000.4, NA, 467014.79, 236454.04, 101899.06, 35960.04, 
 1760857.28, 1162040.99, 961624.76, 167320.9, 4204619.6, 1946831, 
 2103738, 32832.06, 878445, 625553.25, 1276837.06, NA, 356360.58, 
 293533.81, 567421.3, NA, 399723.77, 190391.18, 203457.08, 17524.08, 
 2140499.87, 741313.57, 593964.5, 502218.4, 5504568.4, 2482709.2, 
 4211229.8, 18708, 467092.41, 349188.9, 924921.44, 239522.08, 
 759303.93, 512292.32, 953998.01, 1158785.1, 11099233.1, 7970719.5, 
 13551004.4, 316024.5, 3121648.4, 1856544.4, 4538276.4, 20075.97, 
 738001.2, 368133.88, 57265.05, 60165.82, 908034.41, 594996, 720468.54, 
 24470.14, 547284.37, 312695.13, 85743.16, 19392.96, 878525.54, 
 397145.31, 351113.64, 92456.64, 2751536.61, 946755.13, 1783122.25, 
 NA, 778701.49, 277180.9, 721653.54), .Dim = c(4L, 100L), .Dimnames = 
 list(
c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ"), c("039 ", "057 ", "064 ", "065 ", 
"066 ", "069 ", "092 ", "100 ", "101 ", "175 ", "176 ", "177 ", 
"178 ", "180 ", "189 ", "190 ", "191 ", "192 ", "193 ", "194 ", 
"195 ", "202 ", "207 ", "208 ", "234 ", "243 ", "246 ", "247 ", 
"252 ", "253 ", "269 ", "280 ", "281 ", "282 ", "286 ", "287 ", 
"291 ", "292 ", "293 ", "300 ", "305 ", "308 ", "309 ", "310 ", 
"312 ", "313 ", "314 ", "329 ", "330 ", "331 ", "371 ", "372 ", 
"377 ", "378 ", "379 ", "389 ", "390 ", "391 ", "392 ", "393 ", 
"394 ", "418 ", "439 ", "460 ", "469 ", "470 ", "473 ", "480 ", 
"481 ", "482 ", "483 ", "536 ", "552 ", "563 ", "602 ", "603 ", 
"637 ", "638 ", "640 ", "641 ", "682 ", "683 ", "684 ", "689 ", 
"690 ", "698 ", "699 ", "811 ", "812 ", "853 ", "854 ", "870 ", 
"871 ", "872 ", "897 ", "917 ", "918 ", "948 ", "981 ", "982 "
)))
```

Comment: Please give an example `matrix` - please remember: working minimal example! Why so few get it? ...

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Hope tis helps u now.

Comment: Thanks! but still error - installed `gplots` but `object coul not found`

Comment: library(RColorBrewer)
coul = brewer.pal(4, "BuPu")

Comment: what you mean with `more shade`? e.g. `library(RColorBrewer); coul = brewer.pal(9, "BuPu")` ? - this add more colour tones and makes the darker parts more dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With higher number for colors

```
library(RColorBrewer)
coul = brewer.pal(9, "BuPu")

 heatmap.2(matrix,
          Rowv = NA,
          main = "Cost Rankings Per DRG Definiion (Darker Shade = More Expensive) ", 
          xlab = "DRG Definition ID",
          ylab = "States", 
          Colv = NA, 
          scale = "column", 
          col = coul, 
          key = FALSE,
          margins = c(5,5), 
          cexRow = 0.9, 
          cexCol = 0.9,
          trace = "none")
```

[image: hmap]

Comment: Welcome! I'm glad! (so the asking back an forth and getting the code from you finally payed out ;)) ).

Answer (score 0):

Try with normal code `heatmap` in R

```
heatmap(matrix, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale="column")
```

[image]